# Which webmail providers spider links in emails?

Tags: web-crawlers, email

Does anyone know which webmail providers spider links in emails?

I know that Outlook.com does, because I made [a canary token](https://canarytokens.org/) and emailed it to an Outlook email address and the token got crawled nearly instantly.

I'm doing this because I don't want one-time-use links in an email to be "clicked" by the spider before they're used by the recipient.

BingPreview seems [to be a known culprit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699071/bingpreview-invalidates-one-time-links-in-email) but I'm wondering who else might also do this?

**EDIT**

Due to this question being put on hold, I've edited it to show that it is a [*practical, **answerable** question based on actual problems that I face*](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and I wanted to show that it is possible to give a definitive answer.

I used an email [deliverability service](http://glockapps.com) to test sending an email with my canary token in, to a load of different service providers:

- Amazon WorkMail
- AOL
- Apple
- Azet.sk (Slovakia)
- BOL Mail (Brazil)
- Eclipso.de (Germany)
- Free.fr (France)
- Freenet.de (Germany)
- Gmail
- GMX
- Godaddy
- Hotmail
- Interia.pl (Poland)
- Laposte.net (France)
- Libero.it (Italy)
- Mail.com
- Mail.ru (Russia)
- Mimecast Email Security
- Netcourrier.com
- Network Solutions
- o2.pl (Poland)
- Exchange
- Onet.pl (Poland)
- Outlook (Brazil, US, France, Germany)
- Seznam.cz (Czech Republic)
- Sfr.fr (France)
- Virgilio.it (Italy)
- Web.de (Germany)
- Yahoo (Brazil, Canada, US, UK)
- Yandex.ru (Russia)
- Zoho

And the only clicks received were from the `BingPreview` user-agent.

The list above represents pretty good selection of North and South American and East and West European providers. Middle East and Chinese suppliers are conspicuously absent, so would need further testing.

Comment: @john-conde please note that I haven't asked for _recommended external websites, tools, resources, and software_ - I have asked a specific question about which webmail providers spider emails. I've now used a deliverability service to test this, and can answer my own question, if you'd care to remove the on-hold block.

Comment: Questions asking for a list of anything and/or asking for third party providers/libraries are off-topic here. They are better suited for [chat].

Comment: Doesn't seem very welcoming in there either (Q: "Is this the place to ask about TLDs" A: it _might be_)

So I'll post this here instead and hope it helps someone. I used glockapps.com to test sending a mail to a load of different service providers:

Amazon WorkMail
AOL
Apple
Azet.sk
BOL Mail
Eclipso.de
Free.fr
Freenet.de
Gmail
GMX
Godaddy
Hotmail
Interia.pl
Laposte.net
Libero.it
Mail.com
Mail.ru
Mimecast Email Security
Netcourrier.com
Network Solutions
o2.pl
Exchange
Onet.pl
Outlook
Seznam.cz
Sfr.fr
Virgilio.it
Web.de
Yahoo
Yandex.ru
Zoho

only BingBot did

Comment: Sorry you feel that way. But questions like this also get closed at Stack Overflow and other sites on the network. It just doesn't quite fit within the scope of how these sites operate.

Comment: This question seems fair enough to me.  The OP isn't asking for a recommendation, they're asking about which clients they are going to have to **worry about** wrt a specific issue (spidering links).